# More option menu window changing its position

Tags: android, android-menu

I have **more option menu**(as three dots) at right side of my screen. Whenever i click on that, menu list is opened and after 2 second it is **changing its position** to left corner of the screen.

```
    <item
            android:icon="@drawable/img_dots"
            android:showAsAction="always"
            android:title="@null" >

        <menu> 
            <item
            android:id="@+id/item1"
            android:title="item1" 
            android:showAsAction="always"/>

            <item
            android:id="@+id/item2"
            android:title="item2" 
            android:showAsAction="always"/>
        </menu>
</item>

        @Override
        public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
            getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
            return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
        }
```

please help me on this. How to fix its position?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Just add these options as `Item` like this:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

<item
    android:id="@+id/send"
    android:title="@string/send"
    />
<item
    android:id="@+id/delete"
    android:title="@string/delete"
    />
</menu>
```

do not use `menue` in `item` tag.

Answer (score 0):

You can make multi menus for different situations. 
I recommend to do this based on a activity or fragment. Each fragment can get its own menu.

```
SetHasMenu(true);
```

Will allows it.